# Providing xml data in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, lxml

I have a form that make xml request, after that i recieve xml respond
 that look like this:

```
<root>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>description</description>
   </item>
<item>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>description</description>
   </item>
</root>
```

Now I want to put this data in to the table and render it in to template. Further I want use separate element. For example user have to choose one of these elements and make order. As I understand to do this, i should parse this data using some library for example lxml, then covert it to the dictionary and than render to template, am i right or there is other way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the expected dictionary? `{'1': {'name': 'name', 'description': 'description'}, '2': {'name': 'name', 'description': 'description'}}` ?

Comment: Yes, something like this. Further I want use separate element. For example user have to choose one of these elements and make order.

Comment: Please update your question with expected result.